# How do I add a specified delay to the resolution of a promise

Tags: jquery, promise

I'd like to define a function that takes a promise, and returns an identical promise, except that the returned promises resolves an arbitrary timeout; my code looks something like below; but I'm not sure that I'm catching everything like rejection.

```
//Returns a promise identical to promise, except with an additional delay
// specified by timeout.
delayedPromise(promise, timeout) {
    var newPromise = $.Deferred();
    promise.then(function(result) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            newPromise.resolve(result);
        }, 3000);
    }
    return newPromise;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Do I also need to add a similar function to handle the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but that you're missing some details - specifically your `delayedPromise` won't invoke any subsequent callbacks with the same context and parameters as the original promise.

Try this, instead:

```
function delayedPromise(promise, timeout) {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    promise.then(function () {
        var ctx = this;
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
        setTimeout(function () {
            d.resolveWith(ctx, args);
        }, timeout);
    }, function () {
        var ctx = this;
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
        setTimeout(function () {
            d.rejectWith(ctx, args);
        }, timeout);
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

where the `d.resolveWith()` and `d.rejectWith` calls are necessary to preserve the aforementioned context and parameters.

Note that you `progress` notifications are not delayed with this method, although those don't necessarily make any sense in this context.

Similarly, if you actually want rejected promises to resolve immediately (without delay) then remove the second `function` passed to `.then`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find the implementation of `delay` in Q insightful. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js#L1629-L1637

```
Q.delay = function (object, timeout) {
    if (timeout === void 0) {
        timeout = object;
        object = void 0;
    }
    return Q(object).delay(timeout);
};

Promise.prototype.delay = function (timeout) {
    return this.then(function (value) {
        var deferred = defer();
        setTimeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(value);
        }, timeout);
        return deferred.promise;
    });
};
```

Comment: this implementation has the same issue as the OP's original code - it doesn't preserve `this` or the whole set of passed parameters when resolving the delayed callback.